# Jest cannot find npm module

Tags: javascript, jestjs, svelte, babel-jest

I have a simple Svelte Component:

src/App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Datepicker from 'svelte-calendar';
    let selected = new Date();
</script>

<Datepicker bind:selected/>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

It runs just fine but I would also like to test it:

src/App.test.js

```
import App from "./App.svelte";
import { render } from "@testing-library/svelte";

it("it works", async () => {
  const { component } = render(App);
  expect(component).toHaveTextContent("Hello");
});
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.svelte$": "svelte-jester",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "svelte"],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/src", "<rootDir>/node_modules"],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^12.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.0.0",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.1.2",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "svelte-jester": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sirv-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "svelte-calendar": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

When running this test with jest it says `Cannot find module 'svelte-calendar' from 'src/App.svelte'`. I already tried to add `node_modules` to the moduleDirectories and modulePaths in the `jest.config.js`. How can I make this work?

Comment: The config.js is in the root directory, while it's being imported in User.js which is in modules/actions/User.js.

Should be noted we are using Webpack with this

Comment: Have you tried it using a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-svelte)?